# The semantics of rejecting the null hypothesis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

My professor said that "You should never accept the null hypothesis, instead you state there is insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis" and that led me to a loophole of semantics.

Why is it not appropriate to "accept the null hypothesis", and does rejecting the null hypothesis imply that you "accept the alternative hypothesis"?

Furthermore what would be the most correct way of stating your result if the test statistic were to lie in the critical region?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/85903/119261, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4077325/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take the question to arise from traditional frequentist hypothesis testing, not from a Bayesian
context.

If you are at the beginning of the theory of hypothesis testing, as with the Neyman-Pearson fundamental lemma,
you will likely have a simple hypothesis and a simple alternative such as $H_0: \mu = 100$ against $H_a:\mu = 110.$ Then it is common to say you accept either $H_0$ or $H_a.$

In elementary courses, it is common to use
terminology such as "fail to reject" $H_0$ or
"retain" $H_0,$ but to say that you "reject" $H_a.$
The goal of this seems to be to stress that $H_0$ and $H_a$ are often not on an equal footing.

The equal sign in $H_0$ often
specifies a particular parameter value, leading to
a specific 'null' distribution, which is used to
compute a P-value from the observed data. If the P-value is quite small you can say it would be rare
to get the observed data if $H_0$ were true, which
might lead you to reject $H_0.$ By contrast, if
the observed data would not be unusual if $H_0$ were
true, that gives you no strong probability statement
leading to 'accept' $H_0$, which might be twisted
to mean 'wholeheartedly embrace' $H_0.$

Often the 'purpose' of an experiment is to see if
there is evidence that $H_0$ is wrong and and so
ought to be 'rejected'. [If this experiment doesn't sink the null hypothesis, maybe the next one will.]
But in many instances (especially with goodness-of-fit tests) the goal may be to establish that $H_0$ is, at
least, not unreasonable.

Even so, it may feel strange to say 'fail to reject' $H_0$, but to have no qualms about saying 'accept' $H_a.$

In some of my classes I have made a surreptitious deal with my
students that I will try to avoid the perhaps **triple** negative phrase "fail to reject the null hypothesis." (*Null hypothesis* itself may often be taken as a negative statement).
Instead, I may sometimes say "accept" $H_0,$ if they will
promise not to mis-construe that as a full endorsement.
(Reminders are made periodically that this is considered forbidden language by some, perhaps not
*quite* as bad as the banned four letter words.)

With this background and in the privacy of your own room with nobody within
ear-shot, you have my permission to mutter quietly "accept the null hypothesis." And without guilt.

Perhaps the most useful and important thing is to
remember that the proper result of a frequentist significance
test is to *make a statement about the **data.***
The data are a bad match for the null hypothesis or
the data do not seem to cast much doubt on it.